# calculating the output shape for 3D CNN

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

How do I calculate the shape of the below CNN and max-pooling layers? (written in keras)

```
model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)))
```

Thanks!
  Edit: the input shape is 39x100x100.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact input dimensions it is impossible to tell the exact output. But it is possible to calculate the output dimension in terms of the input dimension. The [formula is the same as for 2D conv](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv):

```
Out = (W−F+2P)/S+1
```

where `W` is the input volume size, `F` is the kernel size, `S` is the stride, and `P` is the padding. Since you are not defining the stride or padding they are by default equals to `S=1` and `P="valid"` (which completes the border only with the necessary values to complete a possible mismatch between the kernel sizes and the input sizes), simplifying the equation to:

```
Out = W - F + 1
```

So, considering `X`, `Y` and `Z` as your input dimensions:

```
new_X = X - 3 + 1
new_Y = Y - 3 + 1
new_Z = Z - 3 + 1
```

The new output will then be `(new_X, new_Y, new_Z, 128)`. The last `128` is because of your number of filters. Following with the polling layer, it follows the same formula of the convolution. Since you did not define a stride, it will only decrease one unit in each dimension:

```
polled_X = new_X - 2 + 1
polled_Y = new_Y - 2 + 1
polled_Z = new_Z - 2 + 1
```

To get the final input, just repeat the above operations to get the following final output:

```
final_X = ((((X - 3 + 1) - 2 + 1) - 3 + 1) - 2 + 1) = X - 6
final_Y = ((((Y - 3 + 1) - 2 + 1) - 3 + 1) - 2 + 1) = Y - 6
final_Z = ((((Z - 3 + 1) - 2 + 1) - 3 + 1) - 2 + 1) = Z - 6
```

Remember that the polling layer doesn't affect the dimension of the stacked filters, so you final output will be `(X - 6, Y - 6, Z - 6, 128)`